# android dropdown spinner design

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I have write this code for dropdown in android xml

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:entries="@array/gender"
        android:prompt="@string/gender_select"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox_bg_image">
    </Spinner>
```

Screen is looks like this type

[image]

it's dropdown height or width i can define but i click on it a list come out for options 'male' and 'female' ..

**i can't cantrol this selection option list..**
can we control drop down background or height and width....

Comment: Make your spinner height and width to wrap_cotent.

Comment: you can also use custom spinner in which you can set height and width manually.

Comment: @PiyushGupta ...is there no option for control height & width in  this dropdown

Comment: @GrIsHu  i have tried wrap content.but not working..

Comment: If you are using by default Spinner UI item adapter then you can't. You have to use Custom spinner.

Comment: ok , @PiyushGupta sir i have got my answer..i will try to custom spinner.......

Comment: @KuldeepChoudhary Nice. I hope you will be solved using by this one!!!

Comment: This is a design flaw.. you should use a radio group for this kind of options... I suggest u to use Radio Button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom spinner Adapter and then use the getDropDownView() method.

eg:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityName.this,
            R.layout.custom_spinner, gender_arraylist) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


            return v;
        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            //change height and width or text size and colour here

            return v;
        }
    };
```

Comment: thanks sir....in my question i wanted to know "can we custimize default drop down spinner" ,as much i know we can't do this....so i have tried your custom spinner ..it's working fine for me........

Answer (score 1):

//it will help you to achieve this

```
genderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.my_spinner_style, subjectList) {
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            Typeface externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "ArchitectsDaughter.ttf");
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

            return v;
        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

            Typeface externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "ArchitectsDaughter.ttf");
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            return v;
        }
```

//above code will help to give background color for dropdown spinner and to customize the font  . width of drop down depends  on width of spinner.Below is the my_spinner_style.xml for customizing text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```